# Replicate html header and footer

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently developing a site in HTML5. I would like to replicate the code for my header and footer in multiple pages. After having surfed a bit on the web it seems that there are two major possibilities:

1. Including the HTML code using PHP
2. Including the HTML code with JQuery

Which one should be preferred?

Comment: use php and have the header and footers as separate files that are  included into the page - allows you to make a change to one file to have the changes follow on through the site. one thing though - yo will need the file extension to be .php for the pages affected to allow the php parser to know that they are php files.

Comment: Learn Smarty for split HTML and PHP and create parts of web page like you want and split jobs of programmers and designers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with php. It is as simple as `<?php include 'footer.php';?>`.
if you are not familiar with php check it out. It will be worth your time learning it, even as a front-end developer.